# Thread: 1 signal SIGABRT class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7.3

I am having this error above which I have looked all over and some answers refer to a connection that does not exist.

All my connections looks good.

I am a beginner and all solutions I've seen with this error are coming either from a connecting an IBOutlet or error in code, but the code is different than mine.

I had this error before and I have left the project and continue with another one, but I really need to learn how to solve this issue or where it comes from to solve my future projects.

My whole project is here.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9jv8z8mve7luh4/ShoppingList.zip?dl=0

connection screen.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1khbq6f8ylhx5yp/Screen%20Shot%202016-06-25%20at%2011.59.00%20AM.png?dl=0

Debug error below.

Thanks for any help. Your time is really appreciated.

2016-06-25 11:45:50.392 ShoppingList[2334:156567] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:6573
2016-06-25 11:45:50.397 ShoppingList[2334:156567] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x001fc494 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f10e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x001fc32a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
    3   Foundation                          0x00641322 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
    4   UIKit                               0x00b61afc -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 258
    5   ShoppingList                        0x0000a723 _TFC12ShoppingList14ViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 147
    6   ShoppingList                        0x0000a969 _TToFC12ShoppingList14ViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 89
    7   UIKit                               0x00b76934 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 822
    8   UIKit                               0x00b76a7d -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 90
    9   UIKit                               0x00b46b32 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3347
    10  UIKit                               0x00b65416 __29-[UITableView layoutSubviews]_block_invoke + 52
    11  UIKit                               0x00b806cc -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 88
    12  UIKit                               0x00b652eb -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 214
    13  UIKit                               0x00abb3d4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 810
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f25059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    15  QuartzCore                          0x05300096 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
    16  QuartzCore                          0x052f38b6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
    17  QuartzCore                          0x052f371a _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    18  QuartzCore                          0x052e5ee7 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 317
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0531a847 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 561
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0531c0b8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17flush_transactionEv + 50
    21  UIKit                               0x009e49b1 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 8379
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0010ee5f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00104aeb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00103f08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00103846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0010365b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x046d2664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x046d24a1 GSEventRun + 104
    29  UIKit                               0x009eaeb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
    30  ShoppingList                        0x0000bff1 main + 145
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x02927a25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: The error message above clearly shows that your code is trying to set up a table cell with an identifier different than anything for which you've provided definition (such as in a storyboard). You need to check that.

Comment: Thank you very much, you just made my day! How can I mark this as an answer? since this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message above clearly shows that your code is trying to set up a table cell with an identifier different than anything for which you've provided definition (such as in a storyboard). You need to check that